# Remove object from array based on array of some property of that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have an array of objects (objList) that each has "id" property.

I have an array of strings (idsToRemove), representing IDs of the objects to remove from objList.

I find some solution but I fear it's slow, especially with the large list of objects with lots of properties.
Is there more efficient way to do this?

```js
var idsToRemove = ["3", "1"];
var objList = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "aaa"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "bbb"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "ccc"
  }
];

for (var i = 0, len = idsToRemove.length; i < len; i++) {
  objList = objList.filter(o => o.id != idsToRemove[i]);
}

console.log(objList);
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Turn the `idsToRemove` into a `Set` so that you can use `Set.prototype.has` (an `O(1)` operation), and `.filter` the `objList` just once, so that the overall complexity is `O(n)` (and you only iterate over the possibly-huge `objList` once):

```js
var idsToRemove = ["3", "1"];
var objList = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "aaa"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "bbb"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "ccc"
  }
];

const set = new Set(idsToRemove);
const filtered = objList.filter(({ id }) => !set.has(id));
console.log(filtered);
```

Note that `Array.prototype.includes` and `Array.prototype.indexOf` operations are `O(N)`, not `O(1)`, so if you use them instead of a `Set`, they may take significantly longer.

Comment: Not sure if the claim Set.has is O(1) is correct. Please provide an answer to this question if it is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057200/is-set-has-method-o1-and-array-indexof-on

Comment: Does it not depend on the size of the array? If the array is small, is it not better to through it than creating a new copy in memory then access it ?

Comment: You're right, if the `idsToRemove` has a very small number of elements, using a Set instead doesn't provide much of a benefit.

Comment: Can you explain me the difference between your syntax and this syntax:
const filtered = objList.filter(o => !set.has(o.id));

Comment: @Dalibor My version uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the argument list, whereas that version doesn't. If a function doesn't need the *whole* object, but only one (or some) of its properties, I like to extract that property immediately rather than having to hold on to the whole object - but both options work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.includes` which check if the given string exists in the given array and combine it with an `Array.filter`.

```js
const idsToRemove = ['3', '1'];

const objList = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'aaa',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'bbb',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'ccc',
  },
];

const filteredObjList = objList.filter(x => !idsToRemove.includes(x.id));

console.log(filteredObjList);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two nested iterators if you use a built-in lookup function

```
   objList = objList.filter(o => idsToRemove.indexOf(o.id) < 0);
```

Documentation:

[Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Array.filter()`

```js
const idsToRemove = ['3', '1'];

const objList = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'aaa',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'bbb',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'ccc',
  }
];

const res = objList.filter(value => !idsToRemove.includes(value.id));

console.log("result",res);
```