# How do I find() an object property the matches values from more than one specified array

Tags: javascript

I've got an object describing various dog types, as well as variables describing the dog I'm looking for:

```
const dogs = [
  {
    "breed": "german shepherd",
    "size": ["large"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 3"]
  },
  {
    "breed": "poodle",
    "size": ["small","medium","large"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 2","trait 3"]
  },
  {
    "breed": "terrier",
    "size": ["small","medium"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 2"]
  }
]

const idealSize = ["medium"] //ideal match can include other sizes as well
const idealTemperment = ["trait 1","trait 2"] //ideal match would possess NO other traits
```

I've got a specific dog size *and* dog temperament I'm looking for that both need to match. Dog temperament should match exactly.

Here's what I currently have:

```
const filteredDogs = dogs.find((dog) => {  
  return idealSize.every(e => dog.size.includes(e));
});

console.log(filteredDogs)
```

It's currently only looking for a "size" match, and I'm unsure of how to *also* match the "temperament" [exclusively].

The ideal outcome would be:

```
"breed": "terrier",
"size": ["small","medium"],
"temperment": ["trait 1","trait 2"]
```

Comment: ``ideal match can include other sizes as well`` what do you mean by this?

Comment: Apologies on the lack of clarity - what I mean is that if the idealSize = "medium", then the dog.size must include "medium" but could also include other sizes like "small" and "large". Contrary to temperament where is idealTemperament = "trait1" then dog.temperament should ONLY include "trait1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce computational complexity, make a Set of the `idealTemperment`, then check that `.every` of a dog's `temperment` array exists in that Set, and that their sizes are the same:

```js
const dogs = [
  {
    "breed": "german shepherd",
    "size": ["large"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 3"]
  },
  {
    "breed": "poodle",
    "size": ["small","medium","large"],
    "temperment": ["trait 2","trait 3"]
  },
  {
    "breed": "terrier",
    "size": ["small","medium"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 2"]
  }
];
const idealSize = ["medium"] //ideal match can include other sizes as well
const idealTemperment = ["trait 1","trait 2"] //ideal match would possess NO other traits
const sizeSet = new Set(idealSize);
const tempermentSet = new Set(idealTemperment);
const filteredDogs = dogs.find(dog => (
  dog.size.some(size => sizeSet.has(size)) &&
  dog.temperment.length === tempermentSet.size &&
  dog.temperment.every(trait => tempermentSet.has(trait))
));

console.log(filteredDogs)
```

Comment: Using include with array has more complexity than a has with Set? How? Will you explain or direct me to  some sources, so that I can understand

Comment: @Supercool.See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057200/is-the-set-has-method-o1-and-array-indexof-on and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091772/javascript-es6-computational-time-complexity-of-collections. Set.has is `O(1)`, `Array.includes` is `O(n)`

Comment: With only one or two temperaments or sizes, I imagine that despite the reduced time complexity, constructing a set would be slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `every` operation on `idealTemperment` as well. But to make sure that "**ideal match would possess NO other traits**", you should verify that the number of traits of a dog type is equal to the number of expected traits as well.

```js
const dogs = [
  {
    "breed": "german shepherd",
    "size": ["large"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 3"]
  },
  {
    "breed": "poodle",
    "size": ["small","medium","large"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 2","trait 3"]
  },
  {
    "breed": "terrier",
    "size": ["small","medium"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 2"]
  }
]

const idealSize = ["medium"];
const idealTemperment = ["trait 1","trait 2"];

const filteredDogs = dogs.find((dog) => {  
  return idealSize.every(e => dog.size.includes(e)) &&
  (idealTemperment.every(e => dog.temperment.includes(e))) &&
  (idealTemperment.length === dog.temperment.length);
});

console.log(filteredDogs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for filtering the desired dogs. Additional needed is [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find all dogs where at least one size matches to the idealsizes. last there is needed [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)  to look that every temeperament from the dog is contained it the wished temperements. Because the temeprament should match exactly compare the sizes of both arrays.

```js
const dogs = [
  {
    "breed": "german shepherd",
    "size": ["large"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 3"]
  },
  {
    "breed": "poodle",
    "size": ["small","medium","large"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 2","trait 3"]
  },
  {
    "breed": "terrier",
    "size": ["small","medium"],
    "temperment": ["trait 1","trait 2"]
  }
]

const idealSize = ["medium"] //ideal match can include other sizes as well
const idealTemperment = ["trait 1","trait 2"] //ideal match would possess NO other traits

let res = dogs.filter(dog => dog.size.some(size =>
    idealSize.includes(size)) &&
    idealTemperment.length === dog.temperment.length &&
    dog.temperment.every(temper => idealTemperment.includes(temper))
);

console.log (res);
```